# Launching new Chrome window at a certain screen position (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have Chrome open most of the time in the lower right corner of my screen and work mostly with tabs. Sometimes I need a new Chrome window (instance) and hit cmd-n.
Now the new window always opens up in the upper left and I have to center it.
Is there a way to automatically center new chrome windows (or maybe maximize them..)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with AppleScript, if you'd like. Once you enable "access for assistive devices" under the Universal Access section of System Preferences, you can use the following applescript to make a new window and resize it:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        click menu item "New Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell

tell first window of application "Google Chrome" to set bounds to {0, 0, 800, 800}
```

That'll make a new window of size 800x800 with the upper left corner of the window in the upper left corner of the screen. Then, there's [plenty of ways](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=keyboard+shortcut+for+applescript) to hook an applescript up to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! It's not what I had in mind, but that should have the same effect. Seems I should take a closer look at Applescript for stuff like this.

Comment: I always prefer keeping Chrome screen-fitting to avoid seeing those sodding distracting 1px-wide borders on each edge, and I have difficulty resizing it again using the cursor if the boundaries have changed. This script fixes everything - thanks. :D

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the standard Mac OS X behavior where each new window is offset down and right from the current window. If you keep your window about 20 pixels from the bottom and right corners of your screen then the new window will open over the current window rather than at the top left. This might make it easier to move where you want.